# Call java from .js in apigee

Tags: apigee

I created apiproxy and used javacookbook sample it worked fine.

But I have a question . IF I want to call the jar from a javascript How to achieve that.

How to call that jar from my js which is in resources/js

Any example to do this in apigee

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call Java from JavaScript.  Apigee Edge (paid) customers can make Java callouts directly through a Java callout policy.